# Can COMMENTS in Postgres contain line breaks?

Tags: postgresql

I have a very long comment I want to add to a Postgres table.

Since I do not want a very long single line as a comment I want to split it into several lines.
Is this possible? `\n` does not work since Postgres does not use the backslash as an escape character.

Answer (score 11):

Just write a multi-line string:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE foo IS 'This 
comment 
is stored 
in multiple lines';
```

You can also embed `\n` escape sequences in “extended” string constants that start with `E`:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE foo IS E'A comment\nwith three\nlines.';
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [automatic concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279375) of adjacent string literals together with `E'\n'` escape sequences for linebreaks:

```
COMMENT ON TABLE foo IS E''
    'This comment is stored in multiple lines. But only some'
    'end with linebreaks like this one.\n'
    'You can even create empty lines to simulate paragraphs:'
    '\n\n'
    'This would be the second paragraph, then.';
```

**Details:**

- Note the initial `E''` at the end of the first line. This is essential to make *all* the adjacent string literals that follow it use the extended string literal syntax, providing us with the option to write `\n` for a linebreak. Of course, that `E` could also be placed into the second line instead, at the start of the real string: `E'This comment …'`. Me putting it into the first line is just source code aesthetics … character alignment and stuff.
- I consider this solution slightly better than multi-line strings (proposed in [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54293433)) because it allows to fit the comment into the typical line width limit *and* the indentation requirements of source files. Useful when you keep your SQL in well-formatted files under version control, that is, treating it just as any other source code. When including indentation into multi-line strings, on the other hand, this results in lots of additional whitespace in the live table comment.

**Note for OP:** When you say "I do not want a very long single line as a comment", it is not clear if you don't want that long line in your `.sql` source code file, or if you don't want it in the table comment of the live table, such as when seen in a database admin tool. It does not really matter, as this solution gives you tools for both purposes: use adjacent string literals to fit your line into the source code file, without affecting line breaks in the live table comment; and use `\n` to create line breaks and empty lines in the live table comment.