# Why can't a COMMENT string in Postgres be concatenated?

Tags: postgresql

I tried to concatenate a longer comment over several lines to keep my code clean and was surprised to find that I can't. For example, the following returns a syntax error at the pipes:

`COMMENT ON VIEW my_view IS 'foo' || 'bar';`

Is there something special about comments?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) explains about the argument:

> The new comment, written as a string literal; or `NULL` to drop the comment.

So you cannot have an expression in that place, only a constant.

Fortunately the SQL standard has decreed that adjacent string literals be concatenated, so you can write

```
COMMENT ON VIEW my_view IS 'foo'
   'bar';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a simple workaround that definitely helps in my situation! Looking closer now I do see this limitation also with SET (the only place I can think of using string literals). Do you know if there is something inherent about these commands that necessitates this, or is it something that could have easily been implemented but simply wasn't? Now I'm just curious...

Comment: I am quite certain that there is no principle behind that, it is just as implemented. In the case of comments, I guess that nobody saw the use for expressions in that place.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-comment.html) states that only text and no expressions are allowed:

> COMMENT ON
>   {
>     ACCESS METHOD object_name |
>     ...
>     VIEW object_name
>   } IS '**text**'

Note the apos around **text**. But you may use dynamic created statements for that:

```
DO $$                      
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('COMMENT ON VIEW myview IS %L', 'A very long ' || 'comment');
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```